# 4 pictures in every corner of the screen html css

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to position 4 little pictures in every corner of the screen. I want something like:

[image]

How can I achieve this using HTML and CSS?

The following code displays a picture where there should be 4 little ones.

```css
div.img {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
div.img:hover {
  border: 1px solid #777;
}
div.desc {
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: center;
}
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.responsive {
  padding: 0 6px;
  float: left;
  width: 24.99999%;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 5000px) {
  .responsive {
    width: 49.99999%;
    margin: 6px 0;
  }
}
.clearfix:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="responsive">
  <div class="img">
    <img src="animals/cat.jpg" alt="Trolltunga Norway" width="600" height="400">
    <div class="desc">Add a description of the image here</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="responsive">
  <div class="img">
    <a target="_blank" href="animals/dog.jpg">
      <img src="animals/dog.jpg" alt="Forest" width="600" height="400">
    </a>
    <div class="desc">Add a description of the image here</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="responsive">
  <div class="img">
    <a target="_blank" href="animals/monkey.jpg">
      <img src="animals/monkey.jpg" alt="Northern Lights" width="600" height="400">
    </a>
    <div class="desc">Add a description of the image here</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="responsive">
  <div class="img">
    <a target="_blank" href="animals/fox.jpg">
      <img src="animals/fox.jpg" alt="Mountains" width="600" height="400">
    </a>
    <div class="desc">Add a description of the image here</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
```

Comment: And what have you tried?

Comment: What have you tried so far and what problem(s) have you encountered? Please read up on how to write a [mcve].

Comment: Just some ideas to help you refine your question: 1) You don't need to explain your expertise, just your problem. 2) You "tried to find something"... what did you try? 3) "no suggestions available". It's hard to believe there are _no suggestions_ available to you, unless your search is extremely narrow. Try broadening your search or looking tutorials on CSS positioning.

Comment: I edited @Daniel Corzo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use `flex`, `margin`(auto), `order` and a pseudo element to split the four elements to build your basic layout.

example below that puts four boxes to the four corners, they can be filled with anything and content styled anyways.

```css
body {
  display:flex;
  flex-flow:row wrap;
  margin:0;
  height:100vh;
  }
/* body:after 
   actually your code gives a container for this */
  .clearfix {
  /*content:'';
  display:block;*/
  width:100%;
  order:1;
  }
.responsive {
  border:solid;
  margin:0;
  }
.responsive:nth-child(1) {
  margin-bottom:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
  order:0;
  }
.responsive:nth-child(2) {
  margin-bottom:auto;
  margin-left:auto;
  order:0;
  }

.responsive:nth-child(3) {
  margin-top:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
  order:2;
  }
.responsive:nth-child(4) {
  margin-top:auto;
  margin-left:auto;
  order:2;
  }
```

```html
<div class="responsive">
  <div class="img">
    <img src="animals/cat.jpg" alt="Trolltunga Norway" width="600" height="400">
    <div class="desc">Add a description of the image here</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="responsive">
  <div class="img">
    <a target="_blank" href="animals/dog.jpg">
      <img src="animals/dog.jpg" alt="Forest" width="600" height="400">
    </a>
    <div class="desc">Add a description of the image here</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="responsive">
  <div class="img">
    <a target="_blank" href="animals/monkey.jpg">
      <img src="animals/monkey.jpg" alt="Northern Lights" width="600" height="400">
    </a>
    <div class="desc">Add a description of the image here</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="responsive">
  <div class="img">
    <a target="_blank" href="animals/fox.jpg">
      <img src="animals/fox.jpg" alt="Mountains" width="600" height="400">
    </a>
    <div class="desc">Add a description of the image here</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
```

Comment: @alej27 what do you mean ? wich browser ? Can you show us what you've done with this template ?

Comment: With Chrome v55.0.2883.87 m on Windows 7, the `div` elements are in a single column. Note that this happens when you click on _Run code snippet_ in StackOverflow.

Comment: Also, I suppose the user wanted to have four `div`, **each with four more** `div` inside. Here you have the four `div` in each corner, but they have no children. Not trying to be rude though

Comment: It does work if you run the snippet in full-screen mode.

Comment: @alej27  it works fine with my chrome and win7, i just copy/paste the html provided by the op where img have width and height set (no mediaquerie added here, thats the job of the op :) so of course is too small .(not offended , feedback is always usefull)

Comment: @bobjoe yes it does in fullpage  , you need to manage img size via mediaquerie, the code from the op gives 600px width and 400px height for the img.  this a template to start from and the question was not about resizing image ;) so i won't do it. If the op understand how to use it, he will do the rest of the code according to his needs. noticed this works for 4 container in body, but imbrication can be done with same base to include also for others containers in each.

Answer (score 2):

Here you go: **[jsfiddle.net/hu7f9d1L](https://jsfiddle.net/hu7f9d1L/)**.

Screenshoot:

[image: Demo]

The idea behind it is we're using an element which will contain all the children/corner, and by using `position: absolute`, they'll stay on the corner. **Use [`position: fixed`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp) if needed**; probably this way you needn't use the `ul` element and change `li` to `div`.

Try to resize the window/iframe, and you'll see the `div` elements stay on their corresponding corner.

Comment: Good explanation on your solution.