# How to put a picture in each corner of the screen

Tags: html, css

I think my question is pretty understandable with this image : (Seems like I can't post images for now... Here's the link)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/VCYJZ.png

I'd want to have pictures in each corners with just a 2px borders taking the whole screen.
Seems like a dumb question to me but didn't find a solution since I'm a beginner. Anyways I'd like to know the best way of doing this, considering that I'll maybe put gif's animating on hover.

Thank you in advance for you help :)

Comment: you can some idea here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41596783/4-pictures-in-every-corner-of-the-screen-html-css

Comment: Please read [ask]. Key phrases: "Search, and research" and "Help others reproduce the problem"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of what you are asking for. Expand the snippet for the best experience.

```css
html,body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

img {
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  background-size: cover;
  border: 2px solid black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: absolute;
}

#topLeft {
  background-image: url("https://images.pexels.com/photos/58997/pexels-photo-58997.jpeg?h=350&auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb");
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

#topRight {
  background-image: url("https://images.pexels.com/photos/37029/pexels-photo.jpg?h=350&auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb");
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}

#botLeft {
  background-image: url("https://images.pexels.com/photos/89775/dog-hovawart-black-pet-89775.jpeg?h=350&auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb");
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

#botRight {
  background-image: url("https://images.pexels.com/photos/33053/dog-young-dog-small-dog-maltese.jpg?h=350&auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb");
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<img id="topLeft">
<img id="topRight">
<img id="botLeft">
<img id="botRight">
```

Comment: Exactly the thing I was looking for, thank you and have a great day! :)

Comment: Seems redundant to use the `<img>`  tag.  Wouldn't it be better to use `div` instead?

Answer (score 0):

lots of possibilities. start by using width and height 50%, then play with top, bottom, left, right. look these up to find out exactly how to use them. also floats, or you could even use a table (probably the easiest).

Answer (score 0):

Give each image a css styling of `width:50; height50; float:left;` This worked with me

Answer (score 0):

Here is Responsive Web Design:

```
<style>
body {
  font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-size: 1em;
  color: #faf3bc;
  background-color: #0976B2;
}

.grid_1 { width: 15.625%; } /* 125px/800px = 15.625% */
.grid_2 { width: 32.5%; } /* 260px/800px = 32.5% */
.grid_3 { width: 49.375%; } /* 395px/800px = 49.375% */
.grid_4 { width: 65.625%; } /* 525px/800px = 65.625% */
.grid_5 { width: 83.125%; } /* 665px/800px = 83.125% */
.grid_6 { width: 100%; } /* 800px/800px = 100% */

.grid_1,
.grid_2,
.grid_3,
.grid_4,
.grid_5,
.grid_6 {
  margin-right: 1.25%;
  float: left;
  display: block;
}
.last {margin-right:0; }

.container{
  clear:both;
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 800px;
  padding: 0% 0;
  margin: auto;
}
img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
h1 {
  font-size: 2.750em;
  line-height: 1.25em;
  font-weight: 100;
  letter-spacing: -2.75px;
  color: #ffffff;
}

a:link {color:#b4c34f; text-decoration:none;}      /* unvisited link */
a:visited {color:#b4c34f; text-decoration:none;}  /* visited link */
a:hover {color:#faf3bc; text-decoration:underline;}  /* mouse over link */
a:active {color:#b4c34f; text-decoration:none;}  /* selected link */

a.selected {color:#ffffff;}  /* selected link */

ul {
  list-style-type:none;
}

.form-input {
  height: 30px;
}
   @media screen and (max-width : 705px) {
.grid_1,
.grid_2,
.grid_3,
.grid_4,
.grid_5,
.grid_6 {
  width: 100%;
}}
</style>

<div class="grid_3">
  <img src="1.jpg">
</div>
<div class="grid_3 last">
  <img src="1.jpg">
</div>
<div class="grid_3">
  <img src="1.jpg">
</div>
<div class="grid_3 last">
  <img src="1.jpg">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, Responsive Web is always a plus :)